# How to push data from a csv::StringRecord to each column vector in a struct?

Tags: rust

How to implement the `push(&self, row: &csv::StringRecord)` trait below?

The input is a reference to a `csv::StringRecord` from the `rust-csv` library. The idea is to append each column onto it's vector.

```
extern crate csv;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct DataFrame {
    header: csv::StringRecord,
    name: Vec<String>,
    datetime: Vec<String>,
    speed: Vec<f32>,
}

impl DataFrame {
    fn new() -> DataFrame {
        DataFrame {
            header: csv::StringRecord::new(),
            name: Vec::new(),
            datetime: Vec::new(),
            speed: Vec::new(),
        }
    }

    fn read_csv(filepath: &str, has_headers: bool) -> DataFrame {
        // Open file
        let file = std::fs::File::open(filepath).unwrap();
        let mut rdr = csv::ReaderBuilder::new()
            .has_headers(has_headers)
            .from_reader(file);

        // Add values to struct
        let mut empty_dataframe = DataFrame::new();
        empty_dataframe.header = rdr.headers().unwrap().clone();
        for result in rdr.records() {
            empty_dataframe.push(&result.unwrap());
        }
        empty_dataframe
    }

    fn push(&self, row: &csv::StringRecord) {
        println!("{:?}", row);
        //self.name.push(name);
        //self.datetime.push(datetime);
        //self.speed.push(speed);
    }
}


fn main() {
    let data = DataFrame::read_csv("src/data.csv", true);
    println!("{:?}", data);
}
```

`Cargo.toml` has the following dependency (version is important as `ReaderBuilder` is only available after version 1.

```
[dependencies]
csv = "1.0.0-beta.5"
```

`data.csv` is in the following format:

```
>>> head src/data.csv
Name,DateTime,Speed
Tom,2016-01-04 09:30:00.038279090,102.44
Tom,2016-01-04 09:30:00.038279090,102.44
```

Comment: The code in your `push` method does not look like a very serious attempt to accomplish your goal. Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: @kazemakase It doesn't look like a serious attempt because I don't have enough knowledge about Rust to know which direction to go in/what topics to research. Still a novice at Rust unfortunately albeit trying to implement actual code and use it.

Comment: thank you for shortening the data. Regarding the `push` method, the basic idea seems simple: get value from CSV, push to vector. You seem to know about `Vec::push`, but I can only guess that the problem is in getting values out of the CSV. Having not used the crate myself, does the [documentation](https://docs.rs/csv/1.0.0-beta.5/csv/struct.StringRecord.html) not help?

Comment: @kazemakase I did have a look at how `StringRecord` is extracted into `Row` struct however the process seemed like black magic performed by `#[derive(Deserialize)]`. I'm also not sure how to adapt the code from a vector of structs (as in the example) to a struct of vectors. https://docs.rs/csv/1.0.0-beta.5/csv/struct.StringRecord.html#method.deserialize

Comment: @kazemakase Or are you saying that an intermediary struct must be created first, and then that struct extracted to a vector? Is there a way to go directly from `StringRecord` to struct of vectors?

Comment: @kazemakase I can't get that approach to work either (error included at the bottom of the link): https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=824619d403115c5fc37d19f859b261a6&version=stable&mode=debug

Comment: As far I am concerned `#[derive(Deserialize)]` *is* black magic :) I do not know how to use it. Instead, I am trying to help by finding out where exactly your problem is, so that others who know more can get to the point directly. Your last link seems promising - now we have a concrete attempt and an error message. (Btw, the error message tells you how to fix that error: *use `&mut self`* - I don't know if anything else is wrong with the code.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do the job, take note that no error handling is done this code is just for demonstration purpose.

Take all csv data and push the name fields into the name vector; push the datetime fields into the datetime vector and push the speed into the speed, then return the DataFrame.

```
extern crate csv;

use std::error::Error;
use csv::StringRecord;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct DataFrame {
   header: csv::StringRecord,
   name: Vec<String>,
   datetime: Vec<String>,
   speed: Vec<f32>,
 }


impl DataFrame {

    fn new() -> DataFrame {
        DataFrame {
            header: csv::StringRecord::new(),
            name: Vec::new(),
            datetime: Vec::new(),
            speed: Vec::new(),
        }
     }

     fn read_csv(filepath: &str, has_headers: bool) -> DataFrame {
         // Open file
         let file = std::fs::File::open(filepath).unwrap();
         let mut rdr = csv::ReaderBuilder::new()
            .has_headers(has_headers)
            .from_reader(file);

         let mut data_frame = DataFrame::new();

         // push all the records
         for result in rdr.records().into_iter() {
            let record = result.unwrap();
            data_frame.push(&record);
         }
         return data_frame;
      }

      fn push(&mut self, row: &csv::StringRecord) {
          // get name
          self.name.push(row[0].to_string());
          // get datetime
          self.datetime.push(row[1].to_string());
          // get speed
          self.speed.push(row[2].parse().unwrap());
      }
}


fn main() {
   let data = DataFrame::read_csv("path to file", true);

    println!("{:?}", data)
}
```