# Using ndarray to create a time series in rust

Tags: rust, deserialization

I was wondering how would I create a time series Array from CSV using ndarray ?

I have this CSV:

```
date,value
1959-07-02,0.2930
1959-07-06,0.2910
1959-07-07,0.2820
1959-07-08,0.2846
1959-07-09,0.2760
1959-07-10,0.2757
```

That I'd like to plot using plotly-rs with ndarray support. I deserialized the CSV successfully, but I know want to know how can I create two Array objects: one with dates as NaiveDate (or String as I'm not sure that plotly-rs supports NaiveData natively), and another with values as f64 ? Below is my deserialization code:

```
#[derive(Deserialize)]
struct Record {
    #[serde(deserialize_with = "naive_date_time_from_str")]
    date: NaiveDate,
    value: f64
}

fn naive_date_time_from_str<'de, D>(deserializer: D) -> Result<NaiveDate, D::Error>
where
    D: Deserializer<'de>,
{
    let s: String = Deserialize::deserialize(deserializer)?;
    NaiveDate::parse_from_str(&s, "%Y-%m-%d").map_err(de::Error::custom)
}
```

And I can iterate through the CSV like this:

```
fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    let mut reader = ReaderBuilder::new()
        .has_headers(true)
        .delimiter(b',')
        .from_path("./data/timeseries.csv")?;
    
    for record in reader.deserialize::<Record>() {
        let record: Record = record?;
        println!(
            "date {}, value = {}",
            record.date.format("%Y-%m-%d").to_string(),
            record.value
        );
    }

    Ok(())
}
```

But know I'm stuck at creating two ndarray Array object. Any hints ?

EDIT: A somewhat similar approach would be done in this topic (but without using ndarray): [How to push data from a csv::StringRecord to each column vector in a struct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50246958/how-to-push-data-from-a-csvstringrecord-to-each-column-vector-in-a-struct)

Answer (score 0):

You can directly read csv data and plot a chart without additional [`ndarray`](https://docs.rs/ndarray/latest/ndarray/#) step.

```rs
use csv::Error;
use plotly::{Plot, Scatter};

fn main() -> Result<(), Error> {
    let csv = "date,value
1959-07-02,0.2930
1959-07-06,0.2910
1959-07-07,0.2820
1959-07-08,0.2846
1959-07-09,0.2760
1959-07-10,0.2757";

    let mut reader = csv::Reader::from_reader(csv.as_bytes());
    let mut date = vec![];
    let mut data = vec![];
    for record in reader.records() {
        let record = record?;
        date.push(record[0].to_string());
        data.push(record[1].to_string());
    }
    let trace = Scatter::new(date, data);

    let mut plot = Plot::new();
    plot.add_trace(trace);

    plot.show();

    Ok(())
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! I managed to use vectors as well to plot my time series, but I'm really looking to create Arrays using the ndarray crate. Somehow I will need to use the higher level slicing operators from ndarray to do more mathematical stuff. For the moment I create vectors the same way you did, and create Array1 from vector using the `from_vec` method. But I find that solution ugly...