# Rust program always says no such file or directory for my input file

Tags: rust

This is in relation to the solution posted here: [How to push data from a csv::StringRecord to each column vector in a struct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50246958/how-to-push-data-from-a-csvstringrecord-to-each-column-vector-in-a-struct)

I just changed the csv data to match my own csv.

```
extern crate csv;

use std::error::Error;
use csv::StringRecord;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct DataFrame {
   header: csv::StringRecord, 
   date: Vec<String>,
   close: Vec<f32>,
   volumn: Vec<f32>,
   open: Vec<f32>,
   high:Vec<f32>,
   low: Vec<f32>,
 }


impl DataFrame {

    fn new() -> DataFrame {
        DataFrame {
            header: csv::StringRecord::new(),
            date: Vec::new(),
            close: Vec::new(),
            volumn: Vec::new(),
            open: Vec::new(),
            high: Vec::new(),
            low: Vec::new(),
        }
     }

     fn read_csv(filepath: &str, has_headers: bool) -> DataFrame {
         // Open file
         let file = std::fs::File::open(filepath).unwrap();
         let mut rdr = csv::ReaderBuilder::new()
            .has_headers(has_headers)
            .from_reader(file);

         let mut data_frame = DataFrame::new();

         // push all the records
         for result in rdr.records().into_iter() {
            let record = result.unwrap();
            data_frame.push(&record);
         }
         return data_frame;
      }

      fn push(&mut self, row: &csv::StringRecord) { 
          self.date.push(row[0].to_string());  
          self.close.push(row[1].parse().unwrap());
          self.volumn.push(row[2].parse().unwrap());
          self.open.push(row[3].parse().unwrap());
          self.high.push(row[4].parse().unwrap());
          self.low.push(row[5].parse().unwrap()); 


      }
}


fn main() {
   let data = DataFrame::read_csv("path to file", true);

    println!("{:?}", data)
}


sample csv:
Date,Close/Last,Volume,Open,High,Low
08/19/2022,$171.52,70346300,$173.03,$173.74,$171.3101
08/18/2022,$174.15,62290080,$173.75,$174.9,$173.12
08/17/2022,$174.55,79542040,$172.77,$176.15,$172.57
08/16/2022,$173.03,56377050,$172.78,$173.71,$171.6618
```

But when I try to run it with my CSV file I keep getting this error:

```
~/rust/vectors/target/debug$ ls
build  deps  examples  HistoricalData_1661097361659.csv  incremental  vectors  vectors.d

~/rust/vectors/target/debug$ ./vectors < HistoricalData_1661097361659.csv 
thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Os { code: 2, kind: NotFound, message: "No such file or directory" }', src/main.rs:34:51

~/rust/vectors/target/debug$ ./vectors HistoricalData_1661097361659.csv 
thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Os { code: 2, kind: NotFound, message: "No such file or directory" }', src/main.rs:34:51
```

As you can see the file HistoricalData_xxxx.csv is really there. but whenever I try to run the code it always says 'no such file or directory' and i can't see why.

Comment: It is an os error, your csv file cannot be found. The path must be wrong or it may have bad file permissions.

Comment: csv file is right there in the same dir as the exectuable, and file permission should be readable: 

`-rw-rw-r--   1 user user 1.2K Sep  4 21:55 HistoricalData.csv`

I renamed the file to give it a shorter name but still the same result, jsut to rule out there might be a typo with that massive chunk of numbers at the end there.

Comment: your code is not reading what you give it when you do `./vectors < HistoricalData.csv`, your code reads from `"path to file"`, which I bet doesn't exist

Comment: I have tried giving it the full path and the relative path, both doesn't work:

`./vectors /home/davy/rust/vectors/target/debug/HistoricalData.csv
thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Os { code: 2, kind: NotFound, message: "No such file or directory" }', src/main.rs:34:51
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace`

Comment: The file is there:


`~/rust/vectors/target/debug$ cat /home/davy/rust/vectors/target/debug/HistoricalData.csv
Date,Close/Last,Volume,Open,High,Low
08/19/2022,$171.52,70346300,$173.03,$173.74,$171.3101
08/18/2022,$174.15,62290080,$173.75,$174.9,$173.12
08/17/2022,$174.55,79542040,$172.77,$176.15,$172.57`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At no point are you taking any argument from the command line. The code only says "path to file" instead of actually passing a filename.

Have a look at the Rust book to find how to parse the argument and pass it to the function instead.

https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch12-01-accepting-command-line-arguments.html